# Yii2 same action responding to different format requests

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, json, yii2, response

I'm trying to create a REST web application with Yii2 using the same route as the application frontend. What I'm trying to achieve is to use the same controller action that would return html in default, and xml or json when specified, i.e. `GET http://example/controller/action` would take me to the action's view but when I specified `Accept: application/json` in the request body the controller would render json data.

This could be done as simply as this in Ruby on Rails:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json {render.json: @model}
  format.xml {render.xml: @model}
end
```

How do I achieve this in Yii2?

I have tried the tutorial on [QuickStart - RESTful Web Services](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) but it would render my html view useless because whatever the request header I send to the app, it would render the XML data only.

Comment: Did you have look to page about formatters ? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

Comment: You said you specify Accept in your request body. Did you mean headers?

Answer (score 0):

About response formatting :

> By default, RESTful APIs support both JSON and XML formats. To support a new format, you should configure the formats property of the contentNegotiator filter like the following in your API controller classes :

```
use yii\web\Response;

public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats']['text/html'] = Response::FORMAT_HTML;
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Read more about [response formatting](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-response-formatting.html).